# SQL query to count based on an id and another boolean column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table that tracks chat message logs

```
CREATE TABLE public.perm_message_log
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('perm_message_log_id_seq'::regclass),
    message text,
    from_id text,
    to_id text,
    match_id text,
    unix_timestamp bigint,
    own_account boolean,
    reply_batch boolean DEFAULT false,
    insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    account_id bigint,
    match_pk bigint
)
```

each conversation has the same `match_id` I want to construct a SQL query that would return the match_ids only if there are less than two `reply_batch = true` for the messages with the same `match_id`

I hope I was able to write it in a clear way enough.

Each row that contains a `message` has the column `reply_batch` which is set to true or false. I want the query to return all the `match_id`s that have less than two "true" booleans for the `reply_batch` column.

EDIT @TimBiegeleisen

Thanks for your answer, what if I were to delete the rows your answer returns in another table? I came up with the query below but it's wrong.

```
delete from already_matched where already_matched.userid = (
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT match_id
    FROM public.perm_message_log
    GROUP BY match_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN reply_batch THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)
SELECT  t1.from_id
FROM public.perm_message_log t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.match_id = t2.match_id
WHERE NOT t1.own_account)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aggregating your table by the `match_id`, counting the number of times which `reply_batch` be true for that `match_id`.  If this count is less than two, then retain that `match_id` in the result set.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT match_id
    FROM public.perm_message_log
    GROUP BY match_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN reply_batch THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 2
)
SELECT t1.match_id,
       t1.from_id
FROM public.perm_message_log t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.match_id = t2.match_id
WHERE NOT t1.own_account
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use the set of `match_id` returned by the CTE to delete certains rows in another table, you can try:

```
DELETE
FROM already_matched
WHERE match_id IN (SELECT t.match_id FROM cte t)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the top part does what I need. I don't understand what the purpose of the second part would be

Comment: I assumed that you wanted to return the actual records corresponding to the matching `match_id` values.  If not, then yes the CTE alone should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I actually do want more out of the query, I am trying to figure it out right now

Comment: After we get all the `match_id`s with the "cte" query, how can we get the `from_id` for each match only if the ` own_account` is false ?